# how to add stepper function to ArrayForm?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I'm working with Angular and I have a form that has a dynamic ArrayForm inside,

[image]

I have created a function to have a step but when I add, another FormArray is created below, and that breaks my application

[image]

what I want is that the ArrayForm keep the same position, not to be believed below

```
<h2> Registro de Usuario </h2>

<form (submit)="submit()" [formGroup]="registerForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="username">
    <div *ngIf="username.invalid && (username.dirty || username.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
      <div *ngIf="username.errors.required">
        El nombre de usuario es requerido
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="username.errors.usernameUnico">
        Ese nombre de usuario ya está en uso
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="password">

    <div *ngIf="password.invalid && (password.dirty || password.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
      <div *ngIf="password.errors.required">
        El password es requerido
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="password.errors.minlength">
        La longitud mínima del password es 4 caracteres
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="password.errors.passwordValidation">
        {{password.errors.passwordValidation.message}}
      </div>

    </div>


  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="suscripcion">Escoja el tipo de suscripción</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="suscripcion" name="suscripcion" formControlName="suscripcion">
      <option *ngFor="let suscripcion of suscripciones" [value]="suscripcion.value">{{suscripcion.text}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" formControlName="promociones">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="promociones">Deseo recibir promociones</label>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group">

    <div id="numberVariables" #numberVariables class="card p-3">


    </div>
  </div>

  <div formArrayName="telefonos" *ngFor="let telefono of telefonos.controls; let i = index">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <div class="form-group row mt-2">
        <label class="col-md-1 mt-2" [attr.for]="'telefono' + i">Teléfono</label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <input type="text" [attr.id]="'telefono' + i" class="form-control" formControlName="telefono">
        </div>
        <label class="col-md-1 mt-2" [attr.for]="'descripcion' + i">Descripción</label>
        <div class="col-md-5" mt-2>
          <input type="text" [attr.id]="'descripcion' + i" class="form-control" formControlName="descripcion">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 mt-2" >
          <span class="material-icons deleteBtn" (click)="removerTelefono(i)">
     delete
     </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 mt-2">
          <mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
            <mat-label [attr.for]="'company' + i">Seleccione valor</mat-label>
            <mat-select formControlName="company" (selectionChange)="filterFriends($event)">
              <mat-option [attr.id]="'company' + i" *ngFor="let chuy of variablesCombo" [value]="chuy">
                {{chuy.company}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="listVariables mt-3">
            <mat-list-item>
              <mat-selection-list multiple formControlName="friends">
                <mat-list-option *ngIf="flagFriends" checkboxPosition="before" #allSelected
                                 (click)="seleccionarChecks()" [value]="0">TODO
                </mat-list-option>
                <mat-list-option checkboxPosition="before" *ngFor="let friend of friends"
                                 [value]="friend" (click)="seleccionarCheck(allSelected.viewValue)">
                  {{friend.name}}
                </mat-list-option>
              </mat-selection-list>

            </mat-list-item>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>



  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 mt-3">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="registerForm.invalid">Enviar</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="refrescar()">Refrescar</button>
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

ts :

```
 @ViewChild('numberVariables', {static: false}) numberVariables: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('allSelected', {static: false}) private allSelected: MatOption;
  viewNumber: number;
  data: string = 'add';
  numberVariable: Array<any> = [1];
  variablesCombo: Array<any> = [];
  friends: Array<any> = [];
  flagFriends:boolean = false;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private usernameUnicoService: UsernameUnicoService,
              private renderer: Renderer2,
              private eventManager: EventManager,
              private toastr: ToastrService,
              private service: WebApiService) {
  }

  get username() {
    return this.registerForm.get('username');
  }

  get password() {
    return this.registerForm.get('password');
  }

  get telefonos() {
    return this.registerForm.get('telefonos') as FormArray;
  }

  registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    username: ['', {
      validators: [Validators.required],
      asyncValidators: [this.usernameUnicoService.validate.bind(this.usernameUnicoService)],
      updateOn: 'blur'
    }],
    password: ['', {
      validators: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), passwordValidation()]
    }],
    suscripcion: [Suscripcion.Basica],
    promociones: [true],
    telefonos: this.formBuilder.array([])
  });

  suscripciones: any[] = [];

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    console.log("afterinit");

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.dibujarCirculo(1);
      this.agregarTelefono();
      this.obtenerValores();
    }, 1000);

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    for (let item in Suscripcion) {
      if (isNaN(Number(item))) {
        this.suscripciones.push({text: item, value: Suscripcion[item]});
      }
    }

  }

  agregarTelefono() {
    const telefonoFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      telefono: '',
      descripcion: '',
      company:'',
      friends:''
    });
    this.telefonos.push(telefonoFormGroup);
  }

  removerTelefono(indice: number) {
    this.telefonos.removeAt(indice);
    this._deleteElement(indice)
  }

  submit() {

    if (!this.registerForm.valid) {
      alert('Alguna regla de validación no se está cumpliendo');
      return;
    }


    console.log(this.registerForm.value);
  }

  refrescar() {
    this.registerForm.patchValue({
      username: '',
      password: '',
      suscripcion: Suscripcion.Basica,
      promociones: true
    });
    this.telefonos.controls.splice(0, this.telefonos.length);
    this.agregarTelefono();

  }

  dibujarCirculo(num) {

    this.viewNumber = num;
    let variablesCount = this.numberVariable;
    let variablesRef = this.numberVariables;
    variablesRef.nativeElement.innerHTML = "";
    if (variablesCount.length === 0) {
      variablesCount.push(1);
    }


    for (let i = 0; i < variablesCount.length; i++) {
      if (i > 0) {
        const span: any = this.renderer.createElement('span');
        this.renderer.addClass(span, "lineCircle");
        let line = this.renderer.createText("__");
        this.renderer.appendChild(span, line);

        if (variablesCount[i] <= num) {
          span.style.borderColor = "#2A86CA";
          span.style.color = "#2A86CA";
        }
        this.renderer.appendChild(variablesRef.nativeElement, span);
      }

      const span: any = this.renderer.createElement('span');
      span.classList.add("numberCircle");
      let number = this.renderer.createText(variablesCount[i]);
      this.renderer.appendChild(span, number);
      if (variablesCount[i] <= num) {
        span.style.borderColor = "#2A86CA";
        span.style.color = "#2A86CA";
      }
      this.eventManager.addEventListener(span, 'click', (ev) => this.selectNumber(ev));
      this.renderer.appendChild(variablesRef.nativeElement, span);
    }

    const span: any = this.renderer.createElement('span');
    this.renderer.addClass(span, "lineCircle");
    if (this.data !== "ver") {
      let line = this.renderer.createText("__");
      this.renderer.appendChild(span, line);
    }
    this.renderer.appendChild(variablesRef.nativeElement, span);

    if (this.data !== "ver") {
      const span: any = this.renderer.createElement('span');
      this.renderer.addClass(span, "numberCircle");
      let signo = this.renderer.createText("+");
      this.renderer.appendChild(span, signo);
      this.eventManager.addEventListener(span, 'click', (ev, i) => this.crearNuevoCirculo());
      this.renderer.appendChild(variablesRef.nativeElement, span);
    }
  }


  selectNumber(ev: any) {

    this.dibujarCirculo(ev.target.innerText)
  }

  crearNuevoCirculo() {

    this.numberVariable.push(this.numberVariable.length + 1);
    this.dibujarCirculo(this.numberVariable.length);
    this.agregarTelefono();

  }

  _deleteElement(element) {
    let el;
    let num = 0;
    for (el in this.telefonos) {
      num++;
      if (el === element) {
        break;
      }
    }
    if (num === Object.keys(this.telefonos).length) {
      num--;
      if (num < 1) {
        num = 1;
      }
    }
    delete this.telefonos[element];
    this.numberVariable = this.numberVariable.slice(0, -1);
    this.toastr.success("Variable Eliminada Correctamente!");
    this.dibujarCirculo(num);
  }

  obtenerValores(){
    this.service.obtenerFake()
      .subscribe(data =>{
        this.variablesCombo = data;
        console.log(this.variablesCombo);
      })
  }

  filterFriends(data) {
    this.friends = data.value.friends.reduce((a, b) => a = a.concat(b), []);
    this.flagFriends =true
    console.log("list of friends", this.friends);
  }


  seleccionarChecks() {

    if (this.allSelected.selected) {
      this.registerForm.controls.telefonos
        .patchValue([...this.friends.map(item => item.id), 0]);
    } else {
      this.registerForm.controls.friends.patchValue([]);
    }

  }

  seleccionarCheck(data) {
    if (this.allSelected.selected) {
      this.allSelected.deselect();
      return false;
    }
    if (this.registerForm.controls.telefonos.value.length == this.friends.length){
      this.allSelected.select();
    }

  }
```

I have seen angular material has steps but I need them is with the sequence of numbers that I have here